# install mysql specific version (Unable to locate package)

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql

I have installed MySQL using below command in **ubuntu 14.04**

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

now checked the version, it automatically install the latest version

```
mysql --version
```

display

> **mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper**

But I need to install exact version of **MySQL 5.7.17** so tried to run

```
 apt-get install mysql-client-5.7.17 mysql-client-core-5.7.17
```

but it gives the error as below

```
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package-client-5.7.17  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex-client-5.7.17'  
E: Unable to locate package mysql-client-core-5.7.17  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-client-core-5.7.17'
```

How can I do this and do I need to install both `mysql-client` and `mysql-server` separately?

### EDIT

Also tried to download specific version using **wget**

`wget https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gpg/?file=mysql-community-source_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb`

but it's not downloaded; see the terminal output

```
--2017-06-05 11:19:29--  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gpg/?file=mysql-community-source_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb
Resolving dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)... 137.254.60.11
Connecting to dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)|137.254.60.11|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html?file=mysql-community-source_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb.1’

    [   <=>                                                                                   ] 16,416      28.3KB/s   in 0.6s   

2017-06-05 11:19:31 (28.3 KB/s) - ‘index.html?file=mysql-community-source_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb.1’ saved [16416]
```

Comment: There is no [MySQL version 5.7.x for Trusty in the Ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-server&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) at all. Did you download it from a PPA? The link you tried to `wget` is a web page with a GPG signature only.

Comment: yes my mistake , Url would be  `wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/downloads/mysql-5.7/mysql-community-source_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here how I solved this

1. Remove all MySQL instances from system

   ```
   sudo -i  
   service mysql stop  #or mysqld 
   killall -9 mysql    #or mysqld
   apt-get remove --purge mysql-client  
   apt-get remove --purge mysql-server  
   apt-get remove --purge mysql-common  

   # delete log and configuration files 
   rm -rf /var/lib/mysql  
   rm -rf /var/log/mysql
   rm -rf /etc/mysql
   ```
2. Now download below .deb files from the [MySQL archive](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

   ├── mysql-client_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
   ├── mysql-common_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
   ├── mysql-community-client_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
   ├── mysql-community-server_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
   ├── mysql-server_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
   ├── mysql-server_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
   └── mysql-testsuite_5.7.17-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
3. Install them in the below order

   ```
   dpkg -i mysql-common_5.7.9-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb  
   dpkg -i mysql-community-client_5.7.9-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb  
   dpkg -i mysql-client_5.7.9-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb  
   dpkg -i mysql-community-server_5.7.9-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb  
   dpkg -i mysql-server_5.7.9-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
   ```

Note: install `libmecab2` if any error comes while installing above package

```
sudo apt-get install libmecab2
```

this will prompt to set root password for mysql; set as you wish

now check

`mysql-version`

**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper**

Reference links

1. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78936
2. http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/universe/l/libmecab2/install/index.html
3. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-debian.html

Comment: Thanks for your support, It works like charm however the MySQL version can be checked with this command in terminal `sudo mysql --version`. Use `mysql -u root -p` to enter into MySQL CLI.

Comment: If I want only the server to install. Can I do that? Right now, I'm getting a dependency error when I try only the server installation.

Comment: Whatever dependencies it is asking for, you need to install those first in order to install